# Importing Exports within extendShinyjs in Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, mongodb-stitch

I'm using MongoDB Stitch within my Shiny application, and to use my query function, I need to import the Stitch export from the MongoDB Stitch JavaScript SDK. The following is parsed with no issues locally using extendShinyjs:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
shinyjs.init = function() {
  const {
  Stitch
  } = stitch;

  window.stitchClient = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("xxx");
}'

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(HTML('<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/bundles/4.9.0/stitch.js"></script>')),
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode)
 ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

However, I get the following error when the above code is called by extendShinyjs in the shiny server: **shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript code provided**. I've confirmed through repeated tests that the issue is through my calling the Stitch export with the first command of the shinyjs.init function. Not sure if there's a work around this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important detail to note: I am running the shiny-server on a container utilizing the rocker/shiny base image, which as of now, uses a Debian 9 (stretch) base image. According to Jeroen (https://github.com/jeroen/V8/issues/86), the V8 parser that came with Debian 9 is the legacy version and consequently, modern JS was not parsed correctly when I was running the script above. rocker/r-ver now uses Debian 10 (buster), so I used that base image, installed dependencies outlined in the rocker/shiny Dockerfile, and the script runs without a problem. Hopefully the rocker/shiny Dockerfile is updated soon!